# What if I don't want to do composer update, I just want to use what ever in composer.json and composer.lock

Tags: php, symfony, vendor

I have an old composer based symfony project, that I just updated with some changes of code. I tested in development everything works fine. I have got issue when deploying the composer asked to run composer.phar self-update to update the composer since the composer is outdated. After that I do the composer.phar install. I get this error -

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                            
Your composer.lock was created before 2012-09-15, and is not supported anymore. Run "composer update" to generate a new one.
```

What if I don't want to update. I am okay this. How can I force it not to update.

Comment: change stat on `composer.lock` file and all entries with date?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The structure of the lock file was changed, and therefor you should upgrade your lock file. You can upgrade your lock file without actually upgrading any dependencies by executing:

`composer update nothing`

Comment: It didn't work. I try running php composer.phar update nothing but it didn't work. And I got this warning back "Package nothing listed for update is not installed. Ignoring". And then after that I got the same RuntimeException saying Your composer.lock was created before 2012-09-15, and not supported anymore. Run "composer update" to generate a new one

Comment: Thank you @gerry. from the issue https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1751 that I created on the github. I will have to downgrade my comoposer.phar to 1.0.0-alha6 to make it works.

Comment: Did not worked. `# php composer.phar update nothing

                                                                                                                                
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                            
  Your composer.lock was created before 2012-09-15, and is not supported anymore. Run "composer update" to generate a new one. `

Comment: This is just genius to resolve conflicts in `composer.lock`...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at the `composer.lock` file and note any versions that are used there. Then copy these into the `composer.json`, delete the lock file and run a normal install.

Of course, you do this on a copy of your software to see if all the same versions do appear again.

Comment: 1) deleted the composer.lock 2) composer.json was correct 3) after applying  composer install still have same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45505665/285594  . Bottom line is not working yet.

Comment: @YumYumYum You cannot have the same problem that has been asked four years ago. I'd recommend asking a new question, I doubt this can be resolved by commenting.