# Zend framework - error wont login

Tags: php, centos, zend-framework2

`CentOS 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64, PHP 7.0.12`.

```
  public function render($html, $input) {
    $view = new ViewModel($input);
    $view->setTemplate($html);
    $viewRenderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
    return $viewRenderer->render($view);

  }
```

In OLD PHP and OLD CentOS its working but when i migrated to new server its failing.

```
PHP Deprecated:  You are retrieving the service locator from within the class Application\\Controller\\MainController. Please be aware that ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer. You will need to update your class to accept all dependencies at creation, either via constructor arguments or setters, and use a factory to perform the injections. in /home/www/html/xxmanager/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php on line 258, referer: https://xx.xx.com/



244     /**
245      * Retrieve serviceManager instance
246      *
247      * @return ServiceLocatorInterface
248      */
249     public function getServiceLocator()
250     {
251         trigger_error(sprintf(
252             'You are retrieving the service locator from within the class %s. Please be aware that '
253             . 'ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along '
254             . 'with the ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer. You will need to update your class to accept '
255             . 'all dependencies at creation, either via constructor arguments or setters, and use '
256             . 'a factory to perform the injections.',
257             get_class($this)
258         ), E_USER_DEPRECATED);
259 
260         return $this->serviceLocator;
261     }
```

**EDIT:**

Step 1: remove the NEW

```
$ echo '' > composer.lock
```

Step 2: INSERT the OLD to composer.lock

```
{
    "hash": "3d8fc311b085e1e9bc4ed181947f205d",
    "packages": [
        {
            "package": "zendframework/zendframework",
            "version": "2.0.3"
        }
    ],
    "packages-dev": null,
    "aliases": [

    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "stability-flags": [

    ]
}
```

Step 3: Remove the NEW vendor

```
$ rm -fr vendor
```

Step 4: try to install and fails

```
$ ./composer.phar install


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                            
  Your composer.lock was created before 2012-09-15, and is not supported anymore. Run "composer update" to generate a new one.  


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
# cat composer.json 
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.10"
    }
}

# php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing zendframework/zendxml (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.10): Downloading (100%)         
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing doctrine/annotations (Doctrine Annotations >=1.0 for annotation features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ext-intl (ext/intl for i18n features (included in default builds of PHP))
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Fallback random byte generator for Zend\Math\Rand if OpenSSL/Mcrypt extensions are unavailable)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ocramius/proxy-manager (ProxyManager to handle lazy initialization of services)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendpdf (ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha (ZendService\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\Captcha and/or Zend\Form)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

FAIL: 
    ERROR: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Application\Controller\mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: OLD PHP means what exactly?

Comment: On my another server working: PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2014 20:12:53)

Comment: On my new server not working: PHP 7.0.12 (cli) (built: Oct 14 2016 09:23:01) ( NTS )

Comment: And this is only thing that differs? Because it smells like you updated the framework on new setup as well

Comment: In NEW server i have vendor directory as below `vendor]# ls
autoload.php  bin  composer  container-interop  doctrine  myclabs  phpdocumentor  phpspec  phpunit  psr  sebastian  symfony  webmozart  zendframework` and in OLD server i have vendor directory as below `vendor]# ls
autoload.php  bin  composer  zendframework` ?

Comment: Any idea? (how to put the OLD one by ignoring anything NEW)

Comment: see my answer I just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that what really matters on new server is your `vendor/` folder content. It seems that once you deploy your software you installed dependencies with `composer update` instead of `composer install` or you do not have `composer.lock` file preserved.

The quick fix should be to simply copy `composer.lock` file from old machine, wipe `vendor/` folder on new one and reinstall doing `composer install` which should be then based on `composer.lock` content.

**EDIT**

> Your composer.lock was created before 2012-09-15

Seems your OLD setup is really old. What you can do is update your `composer.json` to request **exactly** the same versions you have on old system. This is pretty simple, and all you need to do is see what you got on OLD system and make new request the same.

So list installed versions with `composer show`:

```
$ composer show

foo/bar            1.4.3  Some description
....
```

Then edit `composer.json` on new system and update all version constraint to point to exactly the same version. I.e. instead of

```
'require': {
    'foo/bar': '~1.0',
    ...
}
```

you need to put version shown by `composer show` for that `foo/bar`:

```
'require': {
    'foo/bar': '1.4.3',
    ...
}
```

Then remove `composer.lock` and `vendor/` and do `composer install` and you should be good.

Comment: I edited my answer in meantime, so please read it again as now it should be more precise how to recover

Comment: Please see my above EDIT. I tried but the compoer install fails and asking me to do other things (in past when i followed there instruction it screwed)

Comment: Step 1: did this `composer require "zendframework/zend-mvc:~2.6.0"` Step 2)now getting. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Application\\Controller\\mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: OK - Sir let me try your last EDIT.

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2. Failing

Comment: this is irrelevant to your question I am answering. Your code is using PHP module which was deprecated in 5.5 and removed in 7.0. So you must either downgrade PHP to pre 7.0 or fix your code to use i.e. mysqlnd (`mysqli_*`). The latter seems the simplest task as it should be pretty easy as most calls are pretty the same (despite requiring connection as argument).